# ngSmoothScroll from Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using AngularJS and Typescript and got ngSmoothScroll service as follows

```
/// <reference path="../includes.ts" />
declare function smoothScroll(element, options);
module ScrollerSrvc{

    export interface IScrollerService{
        TopScroll(): any;
    }

    export class ScrollerService implements IScrollerService{
        static $inject = ['smoothScroll'];
        TopScroll() {
            var element = document.getElementById('scroller');

            var options = {
                duration: 500,
                easing: 'easeOutQuad',
                offset: 0,
                callbackBefore: function(element) {

                },
                callbackAfter: function(element) {

                }
            }
            smoothScroll(element, options);
        }
    }
    function factory(): IScrollerService {
        return new ScrollerService();
    }
    angular.module('ScrollerSrvc', []).factory('ScrollerSrvc', factory);
}
```

When i call TopScroll from my controller is says smoothScroll is not defined.

Any ideas why that might be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of things going on here.

Primarily, while you have a `$inject` defined on your service, you are in fact not injecting it into your class. There are two errors you have in your current code.

**1.) You don't define a constructor to save your injected dependency** on `smoothScroll` on your `ScrollerService`.

```
export class ScrollerService implements IScrollerService{
  static $inject = ['smoothScroll'];

  //The private keyword will automatically
  // create a property of the same name on
  // your class and assign it the parameter.
  constructor(private smoothScroll){}      

  TopScroll() {

      //...snip

      this.smoothScroll(element, options);
  }
}
```

**2.) You are manually creating a new instance of your service via a factory function**, which means you won't get any automatic dependency injection from Angular.

Either move the injection to the factory function and pass it into your service:

```
function factory(smoothScroll): IScrollerService {
   return new ScrollerService(smoothScroll);
}

//Functions are first class citizens in JS
// so you can just add a $inject property
factory.$inject = ['smoothScroll'];
```

**Or better yet, ditch the factory function completely** because the `.service` helper method does exactly what you are doing here, except it handles the injection for you.

```
//TypeScript is still just JS, so your class
// is really just a function declaration at the
// end of the day
angular.module('ScrollerSrvc', [])
  .service('ScrollerSrvc', ScrollerService);
```

**Finally...**

If you want to get some strong typing on the `smoothScroll` injected dependency you can define an interface with a function definition, and use it in the constructor.

```
interface ISmoothScroll {
  //Better would be to type these params as well
  (element:any, options:any): void;
}

constructor(private smoothScroll: ISmoothScroll) {}
```